# yii compare date and time in model

Tags: php, yii

I have model with rules

```
public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('user_id, name, start_date, timezones, start_hours, return_date, return_hours, location_start, location_end, trip_activity, trip_mean, status', 'required'),
            array('user_id, return_hours, sign_off, saved, advise, time_notification, status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('name, going_with, start_hours, location_start, location_end, location_return, trip_activity, trip_mean', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            array('created, modified, advise, notify_best_friend, notify_now, notify_returning, send_notification, sign_off', 'safe'),
            array('going_with, location_return, time_notification, created, modified', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
            array('id, user_id, name, going_with, start_date, start_hours, return_date, return_hours, location_start, location_end, location_return, trip_activity, trip_mean, saved, advise, time_notification, status, created, modified', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            array(
                  'return_date',
                  'compare',
                  'compareAttribute'=>'start_date',
                  'operator'=>'>=', 
                  'allowEmpty'=>false , 
                  'message'=>'{attribute} must be greater than "{compareValue}".'
                ),

            array(
                  'return_hours',
                  'compare',
                  'compareAttribute'=>'start_hours',
                  'operator'=>'>', 
                  'allowEmpty'=>false , 
                  'message'=>'{attribute} must be greater than "{compareValue}".'
                ),
            );
    }
```

I want to compare date and time... 
In case: 'return_date' >= 'start_date'... it's ok.
In case 'return_date' == 'start_date', so 'return_hours > 'start_hours' but with rules above I can't compare them. 
What's solution? thanks!

Comment: what's `return_date` type is?

Comment: return_date and start_date type is 'date'.

Comment: If `date` is a self-defined class (because there is no such a class shipped with PHP, so I assume you wrote it yourself), you describe rules of comparison and write your own Yii validator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using a custom validator.

```
public function comparedates($attribute,$params)
        {
            $message=Yii::t('yii','{attribute} must be greater than "{compareValue}".');
            if(CDateTimeParser::parse($this->return_date, "yyyy-MM-dd") < CDateTimeParser::parse($this->start_date, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
            {
                $params=array('{attribute}'=>$this->getAttributeLabel('return_date'),'{compareValue}'=>$this->getAttributeLabel('start_date'));
                $this->addError($attribute,strtr($message,$params));
            }
            else if(CDateTimeParser::parse($this->return_date, "yyyy-MM-dd") === CDateTimeParser::parse($this->start_date, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
            {
                if(CDateTimeParser::parse($this->return_hours, "hh") < CDateTimeParser::parse($this->start_hours, "hh")//change hh according to the format of return_hours and start_hours
                {   
                    $params=array('{attribute}'=>$this->getAttributeLabel('return_hours'),'{compareValue}'=>$this->getAttributeLabel('start_hours'));
                    $this->addError('return_hours',strtr($message,$params));                
                }
            }
        }
```

And in your rules

```
public function rules() {
return array(
 //your previous rules 
     array('return_date','comparedates'),
    );
```

}

Remember change the the `pattern`parameter of [`CDateTimeParser::parse()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateTimeParser#parse-detail) from `hh` according to the format of your `return_hours` and `start_hours`

Comment: thank you very much... It's work but there's a problem... I can't use multi language with 'return_hours must be greater than start_hours'...